# synchronization between two calendar in JSF2

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have two calendar I want when I input a date in the first Schedule I automatically displayed in the text area of ​​the second calendar.
I tried with this code but no result:

```
<dd>
  <f:validateBean validationGroups="#{param['validationGroup']}">
    <p:calendar id="debutSortie" showOn="focus" locale="fr" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"    value="#{AAA.dateDebut}" styleClass="datepicker">
      <p:ajax event="keyup" update="formDate:dateFin"/>
    </p:calendar>

    <h:graphicImage styleClass="js-datepicker-focus" width="19" height="19"
        alt="Voir le calendrier" value="/statique/images/pictos/picto_calendrier.png"/>
  </f:validateBean>
</dd>

<dt>
  <h:outputLabel for="finSortie_input">Date Fin : </h:outputLabel>
</dt>

<dd>
  <f:validateBean validationGroups="#{param['validationGroup']}">
    <p:calendar id="dateFin" showOn="focus" locale="fr" value="#{AAA.dateFin}"  pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" styleClass="datepicker">
    </p:calendar>

    <h:graphicImage styleClass="js-datepicker-focus" width="19" height="19" alt="Voir le calendrier" value="/statique/images/pictos/picto_calendrier.png"/>
  </f:validateBean>
</dd>
```

---

I added this method to test

```
public void dateChangedListener(DateSelectEvent event) {
    System.out.println("DateSelectEvent" +event.getDate());
}
```

but I have this error message:

```
 javax.faces.FacesException: Method not found: bean@31f8fd9.dateChangedListener(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you telling the second calendar to update with the date of the first one? You're updating it, but with no value. The most straight forwarded way to do that is to call a listener into the server using ajax.

`<p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="formDate:dateFin" listener="#{AAA.dateChangedListener}"/>`

Handle it in this way:

```
public void dateChangedListener(){
   dateFin = new Date(dateDebut.getTime());
}
```

In the ajax call just update the second date with the first value.